# Why is output arranged in grid fuzzy (especially when printed)?

Tags: output-formatting

If I arrange output in a `Grid`, which is nice to summarize work, the output ends up greyed (or not bold?) compared to regular output.  Here's an example:

```
ClearAll[ display, nplus, nminus, theta, phi]

display = {theta -> Subscript[θ, 0], phi -> Subscript[ϕ, 0]} ;
nplus = {E^(-I phi) Cos[theta/2], Sin[theta/2]} ;
nminus = {-E^(-I phi) Sin[theta/2], Cos[theta/2]} ;

{#1, " = ", (#2 // FullSimplify) /. display  // TraditionalForm} & @@@ {
   {"|+>", nplus // MatrixForm},
   {"|->", nminus // MatrixForm}
   } // Grid

(nplus /. display) // MatrixForm // TraditionalForm
(nminus /. display) // MatrixForm // TraditionalForm
```

Which looks like:

[image: output comparison grid vs default]

The greyed output can be almost unreadable once printed (using a print configuation: `Printing Settings -> Printing Environment -> Printout`).

What is controlling the `Grid` vs normal output style, and how can I change it to match the default output style?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use `Style` as shown to obtain darker text.  Other options also can be applied to change the appearance of the text (diferent fonts, sizes, etc).

```
Style[{#1, 
     " = ", (#2 // FullSimplify) /. display  // TraditionalForm} & @@@ {
       {"|+>", nplus // MatrixForm},
       {"|->", nminus // MatrixForm}
       } // Grid, Bold]
```

[image]

**Addendum**

For further improved clarity, consider

```
Style[{#1, 
     " = ", ((#2 // FullSimplify) /. display  /. {E -> e, I -> i}) // 
      StandardForm} & @@@ {
       {"|+>", nplus // MatrixForm},
       {"|->", nminus // MatrixForm}
       } // Grid, {Bold, 14, "Text"}]
```

[image]

Answer (score 3):

Another solution is to use the [MaTeX package](http://szhorvat.net/pelican/latex-typesetting-in-mathematica.html), which, together with `TeXForm`, allows you to get the equations typesetted directly in LaTeX.

In your example, you would do (after having installed the `MaTeX` package):

```
Needs["MaTeX`"]
MaTeX[
   ToString@TeXForm[
     MatrixForm[nplus /. display]
    ], 
    Magnification -> 3
]
```

which produces

[image]